# Can notification bar be made "always on-screen"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, top-bar

This is a feature request regarding the top notification bar (The one which shows the reputation, comment notifications, reputation updates).

It is nothing major, I was wondering if it was possible to make the bar stay on the screen, while scrolling to the bottom of the page I mean. It scrolls with the rest of the page and scrolling back up if I need to access the comment notifications gets a little tedious if I am at the bottom of a particularly long thread.

---

This is status-declined. 'cheap effective diet pills' recommends *Stack Alert*

Comment: [status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210241/)

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills :(

Comment: Consider a browser add-on with notifications. I use *Stack Alert* in Chrome. The browser's toolbar is always on screen...

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills okay thanks.